# can i access a camera frame in two functions running in parallel?

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing

i am working on face detection - recognition project in opencv c++ , the code works really slow , there is a lag between the real camera feed and the processed feed , i dont want that lag to be visible to the user .

so can i have a function which just reads a frame from camera and displays it . and all the detection/recognition work can be done on other functions running in parallel ?

also i want my result to be visible on the screen ( a box around the face with necessary details) so can i transfer this data across functions . can i create a vector of Rect datatype which contains all these rectangle data , which can be accessed by all the functions to push new faces and to display them?

i am just searching for a solution to this problem , i know little about parallel computing , if there is any other alternative please give details

thanks

Rishi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to run face detection and recognition code in a separate thread. First you need to copy frame to use it on another thread.

Using vector of Rect will be convinient. But you need to lock mutex when you use vector to prevent problems with parallel access to the same data. And you need to lock mutex while copying frame.

I should note that if your face detection and recognition code runs very slowly, it will never give you up-to-date result: rectangles will be displaced.

Answer (score 0):

First of all note one thing - there will be always some lag. Even if you just display image video from the camera (without any processing) it will be a bit delayed.

It's also important to optimize the process of face detection, parallel computing won't fix all you problems. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128637/opencv-haarlike-eye-detection/16131846#16131846) i've written a bit about that (but it's mostly about eye detection within face). Anther technique which it's worth trying is checking whether region (part of image) in which you have found face in last frame have changed or not. General idea is quite simple - subtract region of new (actual) frame from the same region of old (previous one) frame. Then on the result image use binary threshold operation (you need to find threshold value on you own by trying different values - i'm not sure, but i think that i've used something about 30 - don't use too small value, because there is always some difference between two frames, because of noise and little changes in lighting etc). Then count all non-zero pixels and divide this number by number off all pixels of this region ( = width * height ) and multiply by 100. This number will be percentage of changed pixels. If this value is small, you don't have analyze current frame, you can just assume that results of analysis from previous frame are still actual and correct. Note that this technique is working fine only if background isn't changing quickly (like for example trees or water).